# Self-type traits with abstract classes

Tags: scala

I'm facing a design issue that my poor Scala level cannot handle.

I have an abstract class, let's say:

```
abstract class AbstractJob {
    def run: Long
    implicit val someVal: String
}
```

Then, I have "platforms" on which jobs can be ran.

I want to declare subclasses containing real "jobs" (no need to know what it should actually do). Ideally, I want them to be declared this way:

```
class OneJob with Platform1 with Platform2 {
    override def run = { 
        ... some code returning a long result ... 
    }

    override implicit val someVal = "foo"
}
```

Indeed, jobs can have multiple platforms on which they can be ran.

However, the run method on jobs must be launched by the platforms. Therefore I tried to use a self-type:

```
trait Platform1 { self: AbstractJob =>
    def runOnPlatform = someFunctionRelatedToPlatform(run(someVal))
}
```

Unfortunately when calling someVal value (in any job extending `AbstractJob`), I get a null value. I went to the conclusion that self-type in traits are directly related to the defined class (and not the actual class, which is a subtype in my case)

I tried to define another type `type Jobs :> AbstractJob` for the self-type in the trait but that didn't work.

I have a limited number of backup solutions, but I want to use the "full power" of Scala and avoid developers to write a lot of redundant and "plumber" code (related to platforms and `AbstractJob` class in my example).

1. `AbstractJob` calls directly runOnPlatform with an "abstract" function to be implemented in concrete jobs. In this case my users will only write the business code they need but I'm quite sure I can do better using Scala concepts. I'm feeling that I'm just using Java (and generally OOP) concepts in Scala...
2. Let the users write a hell lot of redundant code... Obviously I'm avoiding this as much as possible!!

I hope I'm clear enough!

Comment: My first thought is that inheritance is the wrong way to model the association between the job and the platforms.

Comment: I couldn't completely get your problem yet. But I think `early initialization` might be your solution. If you can post complete example, with your requirement, may be we can help.

Comment: @RandallSchulz You're right. My intention was to use traits as a way to plug "launchers" for job on any platform and inheritance is the wrong way. I wanted to use traits as decorators which is a bad idea in my case... Thanks!